# Is there a way get width and height of child element in a directive in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using an angularjs directive with a template to append divs to element. CSS automatically styles its width using max width. How do I find this width for further processing? I tried:

```
for(var i=0; i<numchild; i++){
    angular.element(element.children()[i]).clientWidth
}
```

but this returns undefined. Is there any way to get the dimensions (height and width) of all children?

Entire javascript code for directive and template is as below:

```
angular.module('components', [])
    .directive('mydir', function () {
        numchild = 5
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            link: function(scope, element, attr) {
                for(var i=0; i<numchild; i++){
                    if(i==0){
                        element.append('<div class="myclass" style="display:table">Random</div><br>');
                    }
                    else {
                        element.append(
                            '<div class="myclass" style="display:table">Random noise here and there and everywhere around us</div><br>'
                        )
                    }
                    console.log(angular.element(element.children()[i]).clientWidth);
                }
            }
        }
    })

angular.module('MyApp', ['components'])
```

Updated this with a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z55a9/2/

Comment: Can you post the template and the directive?

Comment: have you tried `offsetWidth` ?

Comment: Tried it, doesn't work either

Comment: how about `css('height')` or `css('width')`?

Comment: You can use jquery in your directive simply as $(el).height() or $(el).width()  zepto as well.

Answer (score 1):

`console.log(angular.element(element.children()[i])[0].clientWidth);`

is what you want, but you are also looping through your `<br>` tags so `numchild=5` is wrong. (you have 5 div's and 5 br's).